# Unable to toggle between image sources

Tags: javascript, dom

The HTML file and the images are all in same folder. So basically I know this is supposed to work. it works only when i use the src attribute as
 `"file:///C:/Users/ATZ/Desktop/seats/available.png"`. I have tried using
 `../available.png` and it still doesn't work.

```
function changeImage() {
  if (document.getElementById('seat0').src == "available.png") {
    document.getElementById('seat0').src = "selected.png"
  } else if (document.getElementById('seat0').src == "selected.png") {
    document.getElementById('seat0').src = "available.png"
  } else {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please select Another seat. That seat has been occupied";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a path issue. Depends on where you javascript is running from.

Comment: Have you looked what value `document.getElementById('seat0').src` returns?

Comment: @Rash: *"Depends on where you javascript is running from"* It doesn't have anything to do with where the JavaScript runs (from). It has only something to do with where the images are located relative to the HTML file.

Comment: @FelixKling I checked the value document.getElementById('seat0').src returns and it is the absolute path "file:///C:/Users/ATZ/Desktop/seats/available.png" .

Answer (score 1):

the problem is most likely the fact that your expecting `.src` to be JUST the file name. However you have to remember the browser see files based on an absolute path even if its not given the absolute path. You can use `IndexOf`to see if the filename exists in the path.

```
function changeImage(){

    var img_obj = document.getElementById('seat0');

    if (img_obj.src.indexOf("available.png") > -1)

         { img_obj.src="selected.png"}

    else if (img_obj.src.indexOf("selected.png") > -1)

       {img_obj.src="available.png"}

    else { document.getElementById('error').innerHTML=

    "Please select Another seat. That seat has been occupied"; } }
```

updated per @Felix's observation and to fix my typos

Comment: I believe you mean `document.getElementById('seat0').src.indexOf(...)`. Also there is no nee to query for the same element four times.

Comment: You are correct, thank you for pointing that out. Code has been updated

Comment: @FelixKling this works.but when the src attribute of the img is "un_available.png", onclick it changes the image to "selected.png" instead of running the else condition.

Comment: @Engoh: You could rename the images so that they don't share the same substring, or you use `element.getAttibute('src')` to get the value that is set in the HTML and compare it like you did originally.

Comment: you could also add `/` before the image name, that way you won't have that problem.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you so very much... it works well i renamed the other image so it doesnt share thesame substring. I didnt know about the IndexOf() function. i just learned something new.

Comment: @imvain2 tried to alert img_obj.src.indexOf("available.png") and it gave me 35. i dont know why. please can any of u enlighten me? i thought its supposed to give me a -1 or 0 depending if the string matches or not.

Comment: `indexOf` is giving you the `position` in the string that `available.png` was found. So, `-1` means not found, 0 = first character, 1 = second character etc...